# C Linux Program, trying to implement Useradd from File

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to implement useradd from a file. "acc.txt" contains the name,surname and password of a user. After executing the same command manually it worked, but It didn't work while being executed from this program.

After looking into printf("%s",command); the command SHOULD be executed, but I'm getting a segmentation error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char name[] = "acc.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(name, "r");
    
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        perror(name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    char line[1200+1];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
        char login[32]="";
        char full_name[50];
        char password[16];

        char name[30];
        char surname[30];
        
            sscanf(line,"%[^;];%[^;];%s",name,surname,password);
            
            strncpy(login,name,1);
            strcat(login,surname);
                    
            strcpy(full_name,name);
            strcat(full_name," ");
            strcat(full_name,surname);
            
            char command[100];
            sprintf(command,"/usr/sbin/useradd -m -p %s -c '%s' -s /bin/bash -g student %s",password, full_name,login);
            system(command);
        }
        fclose(file);   
    }
```

ACC.txt contains

```
test;object;pass1
jon;doe;pass2
```

Comment: strncpy() with a length of 1 looks suspicious. You should printf each step of your string manipulations in order to control everything goes well. I am not sure login is what you expect. At least printf the command.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming for the content line:`jon;doe;pass2`

will result in the command:

`/usr/sbin/useradd -m -p pass2 -c 'jon doe' -s /bin/bash -g student jdoe`

If I'm correct in my assumption, then this code will not leak memory and also do said resulting command:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void parseLineToCommand(char* line, char **command){

    char *temp = NULL; 
    char fullname [100];
    char name[50] ;
    char lastname[50] ;
    char password[100] ;
    char ret[1000];
    strcpy(ret, "/usr/sbin/useradd -m -p ");

    if (line[strlen(line) - 1] == '\n')
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';

    // Get first name
    temp = strchr(line, ';');
    temp[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(fullname, line);
    strcpy(name, line);
    line = temp + 1;

    // get last name
    temp = strchr(line, ';');
    temp[0] = '\0';
    strcat(fullname, " ");
    strcat(fullname, line);
    strcpy(lastname, line);

    // get password
    strcpy(password, temp + 1);
   

    // AT THIS POINT, EVERYTHING IS PARSED CORRECTLY -> fullname has "jon doe" and password "pass1" for example


    strcat(ret,password);
    strcat(ret, " -c \'");
    strcat(ret, fullname);
    strcat(ret, "\' -s /bin/bash -g student  ");

    // add login?? first character of name + last name?
    ret[strlen(ret)-1] = fullname[0];
    strcat(ret, lastname);

    if(*command == NULL){
        *command = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(ret)+1);
        strcpy(*command,ret );
    }
    else
    {
        *command = realloc(*command,sizeof(char)*strlen(ret)+1);
        strcpy(*command, ret);
    }

    
}

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    char *command = NULL;
    char line[1201] = "";

    if ( (file = fopen("acc.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("acc.txt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL){

        // parse the line, store in command
        parseLineToCommand(line,&command);

        // Print the command to the console (debugging)
        //printf("%s\n", command);
        system(command);
    }
    free(command);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Definitely not my cleanest code for the parsing but it will do the job.